# Syntax error related to SQL Server database

Tags: c#, database, winforms, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to learn to work with database on visual studio. I have copied the following code from a guy on YouTube with no errors, but i still get an error.

I have a problem with the following code:

```
public partial class FormMain : Form
{
    SqlConnection connection;

    string ConnectionString;

    public FormMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["denis_project.Properties.Settings.denisdatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    }

    private void FormMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PopulateRecipes();
    }

    private void PopulateRecipes()
    {
        using (connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        using(SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Recipe", connection))
        {             
            DataTable recipeTable = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(recipeTable);

            lstRecipes.DisplayMember = "Name";
            lstRecipes.ValueMember = "Id";
            lstRecipes.DataSource = recipeTable;
        }
    }

    private void PopulateIngredients()
    {
        string query = "SELECT a.Name FROM Ingredient a " +
            "INNER JOIN RecipeIngredient b ON a.Id = b.IngredientId" +
            "WHERE b.RecipeId = @RecipeId";

        using (connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RecipeId", lstRecipes.SelectedValue);

            DataTable ingredientTable = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(ingredientTable);

            lstIngredients.DisplayMember = "Name";
            lstIngredients.ValueMember = "Id";
            lstIngredients.DataSource = ingredientTable;
        }
    }

    private void lstRecipes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PopulateIngredients();
    }
}
```

The problem is this code throws an error on this line:

```
 adapter.Fill(ingredientTable);
```

The error says:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'b'.'

I tried to look for any error in my code but I have not found any kind of error.

Maybe that can help, I copied it from `SQLQuery1.sql`:

```
 SELECT * FROM recipe

 SELECT * FROM Ingredient

 SELECT a.Name 
 FROM Ingredient a
 INNER JOIN RecipeIngredient b ON a.Id = b.Ingredientid
```

Comment: I don't know if that is what you mean, but here you go:

Comment: Yes, but in general, if someone asks you for further information, it is best to add it into the question, not in the comments.  Also, I missed the query part of your code, not sure why I didn't see it, but I had not seen the rest of your code so I was trying to find the source of the error that included `b`.

Comment: How do you post code in the comments? -_-

Comment: In general, you shouldn't - you should add it into your question.  It is very difficult to read code in comments.

Comment: I added more code to the question. Maybe that can help

Comment: @Touareg's deleted answer looks correct, not sure why it was deleted.  You are missing a space when concatenating your string, which becomes "... b.IngredientIdWHERE b.RecipeId ...".  You should consider using a verbatim string literal (with an @ prefix) which enables you to create multiline string literals and avoid this kind of problem.

Comment: @Joe Buddy, you saved me. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you should add a space before WHERE clause:

```
string query = "SELECT a.Name FROM Ingredient a " +
            "INNER JOIN RecipeIngredient b ON a.Id = b.IngredientId" +
            " WHERE b.RecipeId = @RecipeId";
```